# Expose multiple gRPC services using single ALB Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to implement ingress for gRPC services. When i use single service it works fine but as soon as i integrate second service i am unable to call it.

below is the code for this. My both services are exposed as NodePort.

```
#### Ingress ####

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: GRPC
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <certificate-arn>
  labels:
    app: grpcserver
  name: grpcserver
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grpc-services.dev.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: users
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

This is the result

```
❯ grpcurl grpc-services.dev.test.com:443 list
grpc.health.v1.Health
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
user.UserService
```

Now when i add the code for emails service like below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: GRPC
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <certificate-arn>
  labels:
    app: grpcserver
  name: grpcserver
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grpc-services.dev.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: emails
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: /emails
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: users
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

Now when i try to access this i get error

```
❯ grpcurl grpc-services.dev.test.com:443/emails list
Failed to dial target host "grpc-services.dev.test.com:443/emails": dial tcp: lookup tcp/443/emails: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

also tried
❯ grpcurl grpc-services.dev.test.com/emails:443 list
Failed to dial target host "grpc-services.dev.test.com/emails:443": dial tcp: lookup grpc-services.dev.test.com/emails: no such host
```

I was expecting it to work as HTTP, maybe i am missing some thing.

Please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: `grpc-services.dev.kappapay.com` this is not the host used in the spec.

Comment: @gohm'c, typo fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC uses paths in the [style of `/the.service.Name/methodName`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md#requests). So use the service name in the `path` to separate traffic. To send all `UserService` traffic to the `users` service, use the fully-qualified service name with a forward slash on either side.

```yaml
  - host: grpc-services.dev.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: users
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: /user.UserService/
        pathType: Prefix
```

You didn't mention the service name for the emails service, so I can't provide the example configuration for it.

Comment: Thank you Eric, I will try and keep you posted.

Comment: Hi Eric, I tested with above code and i get this error 

```
❯ grpcurl grpc-services.dev.test.com:443 '/emails.EmailService/CreateEmailAddress'
Error invoking method "/emails.EmailService/CreateEmailAddress": failed to query for service descriptor "/emails.EmailService": server does not support the reflection API
```, 
However Reflection is enabled in emails service and i can run that in local.

Comment: You may not be forwarding the `/grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection/` path to the 'emails' server. Reflection may be hard to get working, but normal RPCs will work fine. The bigger problem with reflection is that it can only be forwarding to either 'users' or 'emails'; you have to choose. But 'users' won't know about the emails service and 'emails' won't know about the users service.

Comment: Thanks Eric, Can you please help me testing this.. like what command to execute like curl grpc-services.dev.test.com:443 '/emails.EmailService/CreateEmailAddress' ? I am new to gRPC world.

Comment: That grpcurl command will use reflection. You need to use `-proto` or `-protoset`. `-proto` is convenient if you have the .protos locally and `-protoset` is convenient if you can query a server that has working reflection, as you can use `-protoset-out` to generate the file.

Comment: This really helped me. I was having lot of trouble why I can't configure the path. Seems gRPC has its own style as you mentioned. Thanks!